# Create a Recyclerview with a centered column with constant width?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

What I need to create is a `RecyclerView` like in the **Google play** app, it needs to have `width` as the parent (`match_parent`) but the content inside should be always contained in a column with constant `width`, so the start/end padding will be variable in different screens and will allow the content to scroll.

What is the best way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: I think what you're trying to achieve is `RecyclerViews` in a `RecyclerView` parent , right ?

Comment: I'd like to have only one RecylcerView with match_parent width and variable padding (start/end)

Comment: What you want is to create a custom class that extends `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration` and overrides `getItemOffsets`

Comment: This could work when using a LinearLayout manager but not in case of GridLayoutManager